# Can a Windows Phone Speech Language be installed programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I would like to provide TTS in a language other than those installed by default, without the user having to install additional languages manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the language is not installed, this is not possible. Otherwise you can change it manually in application launching event.

```
 private void Application_Launching(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
  {             
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");           
  }
```

workaround wound be to create a resx files and load your strings from them.